# Visiting Spain as non-EU family member (unmarried partner) of EU citizen

Tags: visa, spain

I recently got a UK residence card on the basis of durable partnership with my Bulgarian partner. My card states that I am an EU family member and have EU right to reside. 
Now we wish to travel to Spain for a holiday. The Spanish consulate website states that EU family members can travel to Spain with their EU partner as long as their UK card clearly states that they are an Eu family member, which mine does. 
Does that mean I can happily travel to Spain without fear of being rejected and not let into the country? 
Has anyone ever had experience with this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have a so-called "Article 10" card means that you can travel to Spain, under EU free movement law, *without a visa.*

Independently from that, when you travel to an EU country under free movement law, which is to say with your partner or to join your partner, you can only be denied entry on very limited grounds of public safety, public health, or public policy.  So yes, for most people it means that they can enter without fear of being denied entry, but it is still possible.